# Openshift route via Apache

Tags: apache, openshift, reverse-proxy

How do we expose Openshift HTTP/S routes via Apache web server? I tried via proxypass however from logs, looks like apache is trying to reach openshift route via IP address of node and openshift is rightly rejecting it. Please advise.

Comment: Are you using ``ProxyPreserveHost``? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost It is also a bit confusing as to what you are trying to do. Are you not using the builtin in haproxy based ``Route``? Or is this for internal load balancing inside the cluster, in place of using ``Service``?

Comment: It seems to work when I commented "ProxyPreserveHost On". I am trying to hide HAProxy Routes via Apache. (Apache can be put in DMZ). Please let me know if there is better way to do it. I don;t want to expose OpenShift route URLs to public.

Comment: If you have a custom hostname, you can define that in the ``Route``. The haproxy can then respond for the custom hostname so long as DNS CNAME for custom hostname points at inbound router IP. If you can't make the OpenShift router IP publicly accessible, then using an additional proxy hop, like you are doing, cannot really be avoided.

Comment: I have the same problem with OpenShit 4.  No way to get  the original requester dns [requestor dns ] (apache) and always got  (at application layer ) the requestor uri with the Openhsift's dns instead of apache dns name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Graham's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128141/graham-dumpleton) comment has resolved the issue I was facing, thanks.